# Is there a way to extract the answer to a question from google search

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, google-search

I am actually working on an AI similar to JARVIS. I want to scrape answers from Google so that when I ask a question from my AI; it will speak the answer to the question. For example, if I search Google "Google belongs to which country?" Google simply speaks 'California'. I have tried a Google module to extract the information using this class:

```
class Gsearch_python:
   def __init__(self,name_search):
      self.name = name_search
   def Gsearch(self):
      count = 0
      try :
         from googlesearch import search
      except ImportError:
         print("No Module named 'google' Found")
      for i in search(query=self.name,tld='co.in',lang='en',num=10,stop=1,pause=2):
         count += 1
         print (count)
         print(i + '\n')

gs = Gsearch_python('google belongs to which country')
gs.Gsearch()
```

Comment: Look into selenium and see if that will help. You can also simply use a `city to country` library to get the country that you are interested in .

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 thanks It worked ! but it would be even better if jarvis speaks the result too like google assistant do...

Comment: It is against Google's [Webmaster Guidelines](//developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/webmaster-guidelines) and [terms of service](//policies.google.com/terms/archive/20020906?hl=en) to submit programmatic search queries. Running this code against Google is likely to cause Google to show captcha for searches from your IP address.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check out [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension.
2. Click on the desired element via SelectorGadget you want to scrape.
3. Apply provided `CSS` selector from SelectorGadget in your code.

Which will become:

```py
# https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors
answer = soup.select_one('.IZ6rdc').text
```

And which will become this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36'
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q="Google belongs to which country?', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

answer = soup.select_one('.IZ6rdc').text
print(answer)

# Output: United States of America
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan. Check the [playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?q=Google%20belongs%20to%20which%20country%3F&gl=us&hl=en) with your search query.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "Google belongs to which country?",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

answer = results['answer_box']['answer']
print(answer)

# Output: American
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.